# Change default download location on Edge chromium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I would like to ask if someone has tried to change the default download location on Microsoft Edge Chromium driver using selenium 3.X.
On Chrome browser, we could use something like this

```
 HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", savePAth);
    chromePrefs.put("prompt_for_download", false);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

Info: 
Microsoft Edge Browser version: 80.0.361.66 (Official build) (64-bit)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you get any error while running the above-mentioned code for the MS Edge Chromium browser? Which exact version of Microsoft web driver you are using and which exact version of MS Edge browser you are using? Make sure you are using the correct version of the web driver that is supported by the MS Edge browser. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Comment: The above code is to setup the download path on Chrome.
Unfortunately Microsoft Edge Chromium driver doesnt support the " options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following setup (Java Bindings):

```
public WebDriver newDriver() {

    try {

        EnvironmentVariables vars = SystemEnvironmentVariables.createEnvironmentVariables();

        String version = vars.getProperty("webdriver.edgedriver.version");
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().version(version).setup();

        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();

        EdgeDriverService edgeDriverService = EdgeDriverService.createDefaultService();

        EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(edgeDriverService, options);

        final String downloadPath = ${your path}

        //************* Enable downloading files / set path *******************
        Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
        commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("behavior", "allow");
        params.put("downloadPath", downloadPath);
        commandParams.put("params", params);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
        String u = edgeDriverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + edgeDriver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
        httpClient.execute(request);

        return edgeDriver;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

I was able to download files to the desired path using this snippet. Source [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c78)